# docker-compose environment not the same as Docker -e

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using docker-compose file and want to add some ENV variables to it, which are not related to redis itself.

```
redis-master:   
    environment:
      - REDIS_REPLICATION_MODE=master
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      # Domains
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=redis-master.xxx.com
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=6379
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    expose:
      - '6379'
    image: bitnami/redis:latest
```

But the problem is that this two ENV were not added to Docker:
VIRTUAL_HOST and VIRTUAL_PORT

If I am doing like

```
docker run -d -p 6379:6379 --name redis-master -e VIRTUAL_PORT=6379 --expose 6379 -e VIRTUAL_HOST=redis-master.xxx.com bitnami/redis:latest
```

then I can see this two ENV. Why? What is the difference?

Comment: What if you delete the comment? Could be a parsing problem.

Comment: No, Comment is not a problem, I tried already

Comment: How are you testing that the variables are not defined?

Comment: I am having the same problem. How did you resolve this @mbrc? (My question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58394801/are-docker-compose-environment-variables-the-same-as-environment-variables-def)

Answer (score 0):

I used your Compose file and I can see the ENVs:

```
➜  ~ docker-compose up -d
prometherion_redis-master_1 is up-to-date
➜  ~ docker-compose exec redis-master sh
$ env | grep -i virtual
VIRTUAL_HOST=redis-master.xxx.com
VIRTUAL_PORT=6379
```

If you want to be sure that ENVs are injected: `docker inspect <container_id> | jq '.[0].Config.Env'` (you need `jq` installed)

Comment: Trying this I can see that the environment variables are there. But like the author found, it looks to me like the containers are being set up differently. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58394801/are-docker-compose-environment-variables-the-same-as-environment-variables-def