# Why are docker-compose "environment" variables treated differently to environment variables defined via the -e flag using docker run?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Looking at a PostGIS [Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/mdillon/postgis/), the instructions indicate to use via the following `docker run` command:

```
docker run --name some-postgis -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d -P mdillon/postgis
```

Specifically, when running this command I see that the `-e` flag is used (i.e. that the environment variable `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` is set. And I can test that I cannot login to the PostgreSQL server unless I specify that password.

I'm trying to run this Docker image using `docker-compose`, but I'm finding that the environment variable is **NOT** being set correctly:

```
version: '3.7'

volumes:
  postgres:

services:
  postgres:
    image: mdillon/postgis
    container_name: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Ans then I run the container: `docker-compose up -d --force-recreate --build`. I find that I can access the PostGIS database **WITHOUT** a password. This is the equivalent of running the Docker image without the `-e` flag: `docker run --name some-postgis -P -d mdillon/postgis`

Looking at another StackOverflow question: [docker-compose environment not the same as Docker -e](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53865748/docker-compose-environment-not-the-same-as-docker-e), I then looked at what environment variables are being created when I run `docker-compose`. Running:
`docker-compose exec some-postgis sh`, and then 
`env`

I get the following:

```
...
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword
...
```

So the `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` is being set. What are the reasons that a Docker container created by `docker run` treats environment variables differently to containers created via `docker-compose`.

Comment: from what I am reading, it looks like the problem is that the image is using that environment variable in build time, not running time. Have you checked deleting all images, and running it with docker-compose? It should be using that env variable it the first time.

Comment: @bozdoz - yes. I see the environment variables created correctly. From the first comment by eLRull I think I know what the problem is: the first time I created the image I didn't specify an environment variable the first time I used the image

Comment: @eLRuLL - thank you, that was the problem. I thought that the command `docker-compose up -d --force-recreate --build` would cause the image to be rebuilt? I didn't know there was such a thing as build time vs running time configuration. But I did expect the image to be completely rebuilt

Comment: yeah because in this case, postgresql is not going to be changing the password everytime you run it. Happy it helped you!

Comment: The various database images tend to do some initialization the first time they are launched, and that includes creating the initial set of users and running the `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` scripts.  That’s slightly different from “build time”, but if you change one of these settings you do have to delete the database container and its backing storage to cause them to be reapplied.

Comment: @DavidMaze - the command `docker-compose up -d --force-recreate --build` does this leave the volume? Why would this not result in `docker-entrypoint.initdb.d` rerunning?

Comment: That forcibly deletes and recreates the containers (which should be fairly routine, but could be unnecessary) but doesn’t touch the volumes.  See the [docker-compose up](https://docs.docker.com/compose/references/up/) documentation; there are a couple of mentions that volumes are left alone.